# How to set window size programmatically (and without guesswork)?

Tags: window, frames

When searching for how to set an Emacs window size programmatically, all I can find are recipes that include statements like

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
     (cons 'height (/ (- (x-display-pixel-height) 100)
                         (frame-char-height))))
```

In this operation, the target height (in number of lines) is computed, *roughly speaking*, by dividing the total height (in pixels) by the height of a single line (in pixels).

In fact, it's not the *total* height that gets divided, but rather the total height *minus some "fudge factor"* (in this case 100 pixels).

This subtraction of a "fudge factor" is a sad little ploy to get some information (namely, the *available* display height in pixels) that Emacs surely must already have.  Doesn't it?

IOW, isn't there a *programmatic* way to achieve this effect that does not require guessing such "fudge factors"?

Comment: Do you mean `How to set frame size programmatically . . .` or do you really mean what you say -- i.e., **window**, not frame?  A frame can have many windows inside the frame.  The code snippet relates to frames.  The function `set-frame-size` has an optional argument for pixelwise to set the exact size of the frame -- it is the 4th argument which can be either `t` or `nil`.  The function `set-frame-position` can be used to pinpoint the location -- e.g., top left is `0 0`.  See this related thread for examples on OSX and various versions of Windows:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18711628/2112489

Comment: I have not had any luck **precisely** setting the frame sizes (down to the absolute pixel) and locations with the `default-frame-alist`; `initial-frame-alist`; and/or `modify-frame-parameters` -- and, *yes*, I've spent a lot of time trying, including playing around with functions like `toggle-frame-maximized` -- it's almost always a few *or more* pixels off of what I want it to be.  `set-frame-size` and `set-frame-position` work best (in my opinion) and can be controlled **precisely** when adjusting the initial frame, and when creating new frames.

Comment: There are a lot of information in Emacs about the different heights and widths of different things. However, in the end there are some things that are unspecified (like the external border in MS-Windows). Anyway, I have collected a lot of the information in my package https://github.com/Lindydancer/multicolumn (a package that tries to resize and reposition a frame down to the pixel level so that a certain number of windows of a specific width fit).